# TicTacToe minimax algorithm not picking best move

Tags: java, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I've been working on writing a minimax algorithm for my tictactoe game, but it doesn't seem to be choosing the correct move. It is possible to win against the computer, so I must have something mixed up here. I think the algorithm itself seems fine, so I'm pretty sure the problem is how I'm getting the best move. Does anyone have any suggestions?

minimax method

```
private int minimax(Board board, boolean maximizingPlayer, char symbol){
    //System.out.println(symbol);
    Board copyBoard = new Board(board.getCells());
    char winner = copyBoard.checkWin();
    if(winner!='-' || copyBoard.checkDraw()){
        return score(winner);
    }


    if(maximizingPlayer){
        int bestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(Board b : simulatePossibleMoves(copyBoard,mySymbol)){
            int value = minimax(b,false,switchSymbol(mySymbol));
            if(bestValue < value){
                bestValue = value;
                bestMove = b.getLastMove();
            }
        }
        return bestValue;
    }
    else{
        int bestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(Board b: simulatePossibleMoves(copyBoard, switchSymbol(mySymbol))){
            int value = minimax(b,true,mySymbol);
            if(bestValue > value){
                bestValue = value;
                bestMove = b.getLastMove();
            }
        }
        return bestValue;
    }
}
```

score method

```
private int score(char winner){
    if(winner == mySymbol)
        return 10;
    else if(winner == switchSymbol(mySymbol))
        return -10;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Example of a game(Human is X, AI is O)

O top left corner
x Center
O middle left
X Bottom left
O top middle
X Top right (Human win)

EDIT 2:

More code, not sure if the error could be in here or not, might as well include it.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> getPossibleMoves(Board board){
    ArrayList<Integer> moves = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < board.getCells().length; i++)
        if(!board.isCellTaken(i))
            moves.add(i);
    return moves;
}

private ArrayList<Board> simulatePossibleMoves(Board board, char symbol){
    ArrayList<Board> possibleBoards = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Integer move : getPossibleMoves(board)){
        Board temp = new Board(board.getCells());
        temp.setCell(move, symbol);
        possibleBoards.add(temp);
    }
    return possibleBoards;
}

private char switchSymbol(char s){
    if(s=='X')
        return 'O';
    return 'X';
}
```

Comment: can you comment the code of minmax describing how you are assigning scores and such.
I have implemented minmax on tictactoe recently, I can help if you elaborate the code a little.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I haven't had much time between work and school to work on this. I've figured it out though, I'll leave a solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I've been trying to use the algorithm incorrectly by choosing the bestvalue inside the minimax method itself. By creating another method that calls the minimax method, I was able to find the best move that way. The following code has worked for me.

```
public int getMiniMaxMove(Board board){
    int score = -1;
    int bestMove = -1;

    for(int i : getPossibleMoves(board)){
        Board copyBoard = new Board(board.getCells());
        copyBoard.setCell(i, mySymbol);
        int moveScore = minimax(copyBoard,false,mySymbol);

        if(moveScore >= score){
            score = moveScore;
            bestMove = i;
        }
    }

    return bestMove;
}


private int minimax(Board board, boolean maximizingPlayer, char symbol){
    Board copyBoard = new Board(board.getCells());
    char winner = copyBoard.checkWin();
    if(winner!='-' || copyBoard.checkDraw()){
        return score(winner);
    }


    if(maximizingPlayer){
        int bestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(Board b : simulatePossibleMoves(copyBoard,mySymbol)){
            int value = minimax(b,false,switchSymbol(mySymbol));
            if(bestValue < value){
                bestValue = value;
            }
        }
        return bestValue;
    }
    else{
        int bestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(Board b: simulatePossibleMoves(copyBoard, switchSymbol(mySymbol))){
            int value = minimax(b,true,mySymbol);
            if(bestValue > value){
                bestValue = value;
            }
        }
        return bestValue;
    }
}
```